# SELECT *, FUNCTION1(), FUNCTION(2) FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way that I could query all the columns in MySQL such that i could simulate this query

```
SELECT *, FUNCTION1(), FUCTION2() FROM table1;
```

while not having to enumerate every column in the select clause?

What I am trying to achieve is to eliminate the tedious task of enumerating all the columns needed for the query then i would add a couple more columns to include in the resultset.

Probably would look something like:

SELECT *, col2 + col5 + col7 AS "sum" , CONCAT(col1," ",col3) FROM table1;

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What happened when you tried `SELECT *, col2 + col5 + col7 AS "sum" , CONCAT(col1," ",col3) FROM table1;`?

Comment: This is likely a problem of poor design. See normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it exactly how you show.

The terms in a select-list can be:

- a column
- an expression
- a wildcard (`*`)
- a qualified wildcard (e.g. `table1.*`)

You can use any or all of these in the same SELECT query.

Strictly speaking, the SQL-99 standard doesn't allow `*` with other terms in the select-list, but you can use a qualified wildcard in that case. But MySQL is more permissive, it is not as strict as the standard for this case.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99-complete-really/29-simple-search-conditions/select-statement/ shows the standard rules.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html documents MySQL's behavior. It says "Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference." But in my experience it's fine.

Comment: My apologies for this silly question. But then again this answer gave me what I needed to learn.